# RMarkdown HTML as part github pages

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, github-pages

I have an [Rmd document](https://github.com/glin/reactable/blob/master/vignettes/womens-world-cup/womens-world-cup.Rmd) that I knitted to an HTML file. I can host this on my github page, see: [gettingbluefingers.com/new.html](https://www.gettingbluefingers.com/new.html). The problem is that I want it to be a real part of my site and show [my header and footer as well like on other pages](https://www.gettingbluefingers.com/tutorials/RadarPizzaChart).
Is this possible? I now define my lay-out in the markdown file at the top.

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Percentile Radars/Pizza's"
date:   27-04-2021
blurb: "Making radars"
og_image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinKoetsier/robinkoetsier.github.io/master/assets/img/second_post/0.jpg
---
```

The lay-out looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% include head.html %}

  <body>
    {% include header.html %}

    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="post">

          <header class="post-header">

            {% if page.draft %}
              {% include draft-banner.html %}
            {% endif %}

            <h1 class="post-title">
            {% if page.headline_formatted_title %}
              {{ page.headline_formatted_title | newline_to_br }}
            {% else %}
              {{ page.title }}
            {% endif %}
            </h1>

            {% if page.subtitle %}<h1 class="post-subtitle">{{ page.subtitle }}</h1>{% endif %}
            <p class="post-meta"><span class="post-date">{{ page.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}
            </span>{% if page.author %} • {{ page.author }}{% endif %}{% if page.meta %} • {{ page.meta }}{% endif %}</p>
          </header>

          <article class="post-content">
            {{ content }}
          </article>

          {% if page.draft %}
              {% include draft-banner.html %}
          {% endif %}

      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% include footer.html %}

    {% include foot.html %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding the HTML to a markdown file (open the knitted file in a text editor) and tried adding the lay-out rules to it. This didn't work. Is there a way to do this? Or am I looking for something that's impossible?

Comment: You can use `html_document:includes: ...` in Rmd to add in header and after body. Check out the documentation: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/include-html.html. With this you can include your individual header/footer.

Comment: @Ray Thanks. If i understand it correctly I need to put all the html files for head,footer etc. in my working directory and than knit? There isn't a way to always shot my site header so it changes if I make adjustments to it?

Comment: we speak computers ... thus there must be a way. Conceptually, you knit a `Rmd` file within a project/folder. You can call the render function and assign specific output directories. I never tried it and it is probably not good/best practice, but you should be able to "port" your Rmd-html to another folder. Equally, you can break the project folder and access files outside (e.g. "../") to move out of your project. Obviously, this limits portability/reproducibility, however, if this is a personal / you-only project that might work.

Comment: Another option - outside my expertise - is to create an own Rmd template. This should allow to include other file/fragments (e.g. header/footer html from another folder).

Comment: I put the html in the _includes folder and included it in a layout. The only thing to do is make a new scss file because the style elements are inherited from the head. You can see the difference between this one:
https://www.gettingbluefingers.com/xrank

And this one (as it is intended)
https://www.gettingbluefingers.com/rank

Comment: Looks/sounds good: "goed gedaan!". You can include css in YAML and/or an own code-chunk (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html).

Comment: haha thanks. Yeah, I added some css, to the document, but it keeps getting overruled. So enough to learn later today to fix that.